# AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError when run in localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I get this network error when I wnat to get api products
this is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('https://api.digikala.com/v1/categories/mobile-phone/brands/apple/search/')
  .then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
  })
}, [])

return (
  <div>App</div>
)
}
```

and this is my error:

```
ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40384:14)
ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40384:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add catch, like this:

```js
axios.get('https://api.digikala.com/v1/categories/mobile-phone/brands/apple/search/').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```